# text family, weight and line height is not work by bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am taking practice for adding grid layouts by bootstrap.  I am trying to add the font into the , however there have no effect for what I added.  I am actually taking the lesson, this is unbelievable that the teacher could change the font style, line height and the text weight but not me; even though I was copying what she was teaching me.

Does everyone could help me and give me advice for it?

[image: This is what i done, nothing change]
[image: This is the teacher done]

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;}

css
#title{background-color: #ff4c68;

}

h1{
  font-family: "Montserrat-black";
  font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
      <button type="button">Download</button>
      <button type="button">Download</button>
      </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is that `css` really in your CSS?

Comment: Code seems to run fine here....

Comment: Yes the mentioned for what i input is in my css but is not effecting in my screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the logic, my custom styles are not overriding the bootstrap styles, all I need to do is move the link to your custom stylesheet to a line after the bootstrap CDN link:

This means that my first load the default bootstrap styles, then you can override some of those components with my own custom CSS.

Unlike CSS and JavaScript, HTML code is executed from top to bottom so the order of your code matters.

P.S: it also work in !important but not recommend at this stage.

```css
#title{background-color: #ff4c68;

}

h1{font-family: "Montserrat";
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 3rem;
line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;400;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  
  </head>

<body>

  <section id="title">
  
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
      <button type="button">Download</button>
      <button type="button">Download</button>
      </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
      </div>
  </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: completed]

Answer (score 1):

To implement the font called *Montserrat*, this code from [**Google Fonts**](https://fonts.google.com/) should be pasted in your `<head>` before any reference to your stylesheets recalling it:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

The correct order is:

1. the two `<link>` tags above first,
2. the `<link>` to bootstrap.css file goes second,
3. the `<link>` to your css file(s) as last.

Comment: I have tried for many time and I finally found the clue.  Your answer is very close and logic.  and I will provide the answer in the coming comment.

Comment: @anpanman good! Also, do not use `font-family: "Montserrat-black"` but `font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;` and `font-weight: 600;` instead :)

Answer (score 0):

I see your CSS code is overwritten by Bootstrap styling.

Try to put your CSS code under bootstrap link to avoid it to be overwritten:

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="yours.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when bootstrap overwrites its code. You can add !important to your CSS or just add a style tag in HTML and style it. Also if you haven't added links to fonts it will always not show your fonts. You can easily find fonts on google fonts. These 2 tricks are different ticks so please don't use them at the same time. But using it is not a good practice. Another thing is to change links like this `<link href="bootstrap.css"><!--then the other file--><link href="yourcssfilename.css>`

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif!important;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif!important;
 }

css
#title{background-color: #ff4c68!important;

}

h1{
  font-family: "Montserrat-black"!important;
  font-size: 3rem!important;
    line-height: 1.5!important;
  }
```

```html
   <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6"><!-- Cursive font used to just show you, You can change late on -->
          <h1 style="font-family: cursive!important; font-size: 3rem!important; line-height: 1.5!important">Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
          <button type="button">Download</button>
          <button type="button">Download</button>
          </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Using `!important` is definitely a bad practice when writing CSS. It should be avoided every time it is possible...like here.

Comment: I know that He didn't give the starting code so I was confused that he had already done it, I am just giving an alternate to it.

Comment: Also, Now I have written about the link should be shifted up or down

Comment: let me see but i haven't complete yet

Comment: Btw I know that this is the course by dr angela yu on udemy.